# Array / Dataframe manipulation in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataframe, indexing

Is there an efficient way to create an array or dataframe that outputs the following (don't need the Price column in the far left and top rows):

```
                    18.00     18.50      17.25        12.50      14.50 
Price   Date    12/18/1992  12/21/1992  12/22/1992  12/23/1992  12/24/1992
 18.00  12/18/1992  0%        3%         -4%          -31%       -19%
 18.50  12/21/1992            0%         -7%          -32%       -22%
 17.25  12/22/1992                        0%          -28%       -16%
```

The input would be a csv file with 1 column, indexed by a list of dates. So for the example above it would be:

```
Date    Price
12/18/1992   18.00 
12/21/1992   18.50 
12/22/1992   17.25
```

I'm trying to calculate the price change for every date pair that's chronological. So date_1 / date_0, date_2 / date_0, and so forth. I want to leave blanks in the date pairs that aren't chronological.

So far i just have this...:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_loc = "C:\\Users\\Price Data\\CL1.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file_loc, parse_dates = True)
df.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to create a new dataframe that contains pairwise comparisons of all the data in your first frame.  You also want this new frame to have columns and indices labeled by both price and date.  You can achieve this by adding the following after the code you supplied:

```
# Get the data for your columns and indices
prices = df['Price']
dates = df.index

# create column/index data as a list
table_labels = list(zip(prices,dates))

# create a dataframe
pairwise_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=table_labels,index=table_labels)

# fill it with your data
# a percentage in the upper triangle, or an empty space in the lower triangle
for p1,d1 in table_labels:    
    for p2,d2 in table_labels: 
        pairwise_df.loc[(p1,d1),(p2,d2)] = (p2-p1)/p1*100 if d2 >= d1 else ''
print(pairwise_df)
```

This should achieve the two goals I listed.

Comment: This is great! Wondering if there's a way to make this process faster - I have 5000 dates so it's taking forever to run.

Comment: Can you vectorize the inner loop? Compute entire rows at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas and numpy functions like this:

```
df_out = (pd.crosstab([df['Price'],df['Date']],[df['Price'],df['Date']])
            .apply(lambda x: (x.name[0]-x.index.get_level_values(0))/
                              x.index.get_level_values(0)*100).round(0).astype(int)
            .sort_index(level=1)
            .sort_index(level=1, axis=1))

df_out = df_out.where(np.triu(np.ones(df_out.shape, dtype=bool)))

df_out
```

Output:

```
Price                 18.00      18.50      17.25      12.50      14.50
Date             12/18/1992 12/21/1992 12/22/1992 12/23/1992 12/24/1992
Price Date                                                             
18.00 12/18/1992        0.0        3.0       -4.0      -31.0        -19
18.50 12/21/1992        NaN        0.0       -7.0      -32.0        -22
17.25 12/22/1992        NaN        NaN        0.0      -28.0        -16
12.50 12/23/1992        NaN        NaN        NaN        0.0         16
14.50 12/24/1992        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN          0
```